# How Can I Programmatically Change the Title Property on Custom Intent For Siri Shortcut?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, siri, sirishortcuts

I want to programmatically change the title language of my custom intent to the preferred Language of the user's phone. So it must be dynamic. There is no localization in my application. But I already get the user pref lang with Locale.preferredLanguages.

**The main question is;** I couldn't find anything if I programmatically manipulate the intents title property.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Thx.

Comment: Did you able to update the title dynamically ?